# when I input 4 abcd bcda cdab dabc,I want the result 1,but it turn out to be 4,I don't know why?

Tags: java

when I input

```
4 
abcd
bcda
cdab
dabc
```

I want the result 1, but it turn out to be 4, I don't know why?

```
public class Test2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int N = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    String[] strArr = new String[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        strArr[i] = sc.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println(fun(strArr));
}

public static int fun(String[] arr) {
    TreeSet<String> treeSet = new TreeSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        char[] chars = arr[i].toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(chars);
        treeSet.add(chars.toString());
    }
    return treeSet.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Scanner.nextLine() will read all your content from that line (starting after the int value which was read) as a single String value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your working code:

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int N = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    String[] strArr = new String[N];
    // StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        strArr[i] = sc.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println(fun(strArr));
}

public static int fun(final String[] arr) {
    TreeSet<String> set = new TreeSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        char[] chars = arr[i].toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(chars);
        set.add(new String(chars));
    }
    return set.size();
}
```

The problem is as you can see the toString of chars delivers you the memory address representation. therefore you get 4 items as it is always a new instance of the same string.

Comment: Could you please define "not work". In my case it asks me first the amount to enter. So I enter '4'. After that I start entering (all followed by enter) 'abcd', 'bcda', 'cdab', and 'dabc'. After the last enter it returns 1.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `treeSet.add(chars.toString());` which actually refers to `Object.toString()` which formats the array as something like `[C@39ed3c8d`.

If you use:

```
treeSet.add(Arrays.toString(chars));
```

the strings will look like `[a, b, c, d]` which should then do what you want.